# Angular animation not working requires peer of angular/core@5.1.2?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-animations

**Update(EDIT):**

I did

```
npm i -g npm-check-updates
npm-check-updates -u
npm install
```

and now it shows these error

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):

npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm WARN @angular/animations@5.1.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@5.1.2 but none was installed.

npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@5.1.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.4.2 <2.6 but none was installed.

npm WARN tsickle@0.25.5 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.4.2 <2.6 but none was installed.
```

and the browser shows this:

> ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir
>   'E:\xuf\Angular\Practice\todo\node_modules\webpack\hot' @
>   (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:0 @ multi
>   webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:0 ./src/main.ts

---

---

I installed angular animations with this command

> npm install @angular/animations --save

This error showed up and the animations dont work too. what went wrong?

> @angular/animations@5.1.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@5.1.2 but
>   none was installed

result of ng -v

```
Angular CLI: 1.5.5
Node: 6.11.4
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.1.1
... common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms, http
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

@angular/animations: 5.1.2
@angular/cli: 1.5.5
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.36
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.22
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.42
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.8.5
@schematics/angular: 0.1.11
@schematics/schematics: 0.0.11
typescript: 2.4.2
webpack: 3.8.1
```

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "todo",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.1.2",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "ng-pick-datetime": "^5.0.0-beta.15",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.2",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~8.5.2",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.2.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.0.2",
    "tslint": "~5.8.0",
    "typescript": "~2.6.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Post your package.json and btw try `npm update`?

Comment: @smnbbrv look i edited the original post

Comment: then `npm update` should resolve the issue

Comment: @smnbbrv let me try